# download tool files from web browser of my Liberty server

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I would like to use my running server as a repository of files that my users can download from a link.
is this possible with liberty?
Is there a configuration that will allow me to do this ?

thanks 
Stefania
C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\myServerApp>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7B77-7220

Directory of C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\myServerApp

01/12/2018  10:26 AM              .
01/12/2018  10:26 AM              ..
01/12/2018  11:01 AM              apps
01/15/2018  12:04 PM              dropins
01/15/2018  12:05 PM              logs
01/12/2018  10:26 AM              resources
01/12/2018  10:26 AM                25 server.env
01/12/2018  10:26 AM             2,300 server.xml
01/15/2018  12:04 PM              temp
01/15/2018  12:04 PM              workarea
               2 File(s)          2,325 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  68,651,966,464 bytes free

Answer (score 1):

You can put any downloadable files you like in a hello-world .war file and they'll be downloadable over HTTP.  It's silly to use an application server without an application.

Answer (score 0):

Liberty is not intended to be used as a generic file server.  That said, there are MBean operations supporting file transfer capabilities via the Liberty REST Connector.  Javadoc for these operations may be found at `<liberty-install-root>/dev/api/ibm/javadoc/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.restConnector_1.3-javadoc.zip`